# Why does this SVG work when saved as html, but not as svg?

Tags: svg

If I save the following as test.html it works fine in the browser, but if I save it as test.svg it doesn't animate.

```
<svg width="1920" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 800 300">
<circle id = "internalcircle" r="100" cx="100" cy="50" stroke = "#999" fill = "none"   stroke-dasharray="4"/>
<circle id = "internalcircle" r="60" cx="100" cy="50" stroke = "#999" fill = "none"   stroke-dasharray="4"/>
    <g>
    <circle  id="1" r="16"  fill="white"  stroke="#999" cx="-50" cy="0"  >
        <animatemotion
                path = "M50,50
                a100,100 0 1,0 200,0
                a100,100 0 1,0 -200,0
                "
                xlink:href="#1"
                dur="18s"
                repeatCount="indefinite"
        begin="0s"
        />
    </circle>
    <text id="t1"  x="-50" text-anchor="middle" fill="#555" font-size="8px" font-family="Arial" dy=".3em">Balloon
        <animatemotion
                path = "M50,50
                a100,100 0 1,0 200,0
                a100,100 0 1,0 -200,0
                "
                dur="18s"
                repeatCount="indefinite"
        > 

        </animatemotion>
    </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

How do I make it work like svg included in html as follow ?

```
<html>
    <img src="test.svg" alt="" />
</html>
```

Comment: SVG is case sensitive and the tag is called animateMotion rather than animatemotion. You also need to declare the SVG and xlink namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Running it through SVG Sanitiser produces this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="1920" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 800 300">
  <circle id="internalcircle" r="100" cx="100" cy="50" stroke="#999" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="4"></circle>
  <circle id="internalcircle" r="60" cx="100" cy="50" stroke="#999" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="4"></circle>
  <g>
    <circle id="1" r="16" fill="white" stroke="#999" cx="-50" cy="0">
      <animatemotion path="M50,50                 a100,100 0 1,0 200,0                 a100,100 0 1,0 -200,0                 " xlink:href="#1" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0s"></animatemotion>
    </circle>
    <text id="t1" x="-50" text-anchor="middle" fill="#555" font-size="8px" font-family="Arial" dy=".3em">Balloon
        <animatemotion path="M50,50                 a100,100 0 1,0 200,0                 a100,100 0 1,0 -200,0                 " dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite">

        </animatemotion>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As far as I can see the only difference is the XML declaration.